# How to ignore files after being committed while allowing them to stay on the repository?

Tags: git, gitignore

There are some legacy files which exist on my repository. I would like to allow these files to remain on the repository for historical purposes. I would like to now ignore these files such that changes to them are not recognized.

Simply adding the directory to the `.gitignore` file does not work. Changes to files in that directory are still tracked, changes can be staged and committed.

Can this be achieved?

Comment: In what way does it "not work"? That's exactly what .gitignore does. Please revise to provide more detail.

Answer (score 2):

If the file is present in the current commit, it's tracked regardless of `.gitignore`.

You will need to remove the file from your new commits (e.g. using `git rm --cached file` if you want to keep the file, or `git rm file` if you don't).